# Сайт фиксирует работу selenium, как скрыть selenium от браузера

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

Всем привет, пишу парсер для ozon seller на selenium, сайт каким-то образом определяет работу selenium. Нужно входить в личный кабинет ozon seller по номеру телефона, но когда есть какой-то код selenium, форма не отправляется "Произошла ошибка. Попробуйте ещё раз"

**1. Добавил**

```
  await Options.excludeSwitches("enable-logging");

  await Options.addArguments("Mozilla/5.0 (platform; rv:geckoversion) Gecko/geckotrail Firefox/firefoxversion") 

  await Options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features");

  await Options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
```

**2. Сделал размер экрана максимальным**

```
await driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

**3. Добавил**

```
 await driver.executeScript("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
```

И такой

```
const cdpConnection = await driver.createCDPConnection('page');

  await cdpConnection.execute(
    'Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument', {
      source: `
          const newProto = navigator.__proto__;
          delete newProto.webdriver;
          navigator.__proto__ = newProto;
      `
  }
  );
```

**4. Поменял название переменной $cdc_ в chromedriver.exe**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver

**5. Добавил задержку на каждое действие**

**6. Пробовал использовать различные user-agent**

**7. Использовал proxy, но ozon seller тогда вообще не давал доступ**

Мне нужно входить в личный кабинет ozon seller, собирать отзывы о товарах и автоматически на них отвечать. У ozon seller есть api, но у него нет функционала работы с отзывами

```
const {Builder, Browser, By, Key, until, Capabilities } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const Chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

(async function example() {
  const Options = await new Chrome.Options();
  await Options.excludeSwitches("enable-logging");
  await Options.addArguments("Chrome/113.0.0.0 ") 
  await Options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features");
  await Options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
  
  
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setChromeOptions(Options).build();

  await driver.manage().window().maximize();

  await driver.executeScript("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")

  const cdpConnection = await driver.createCDPConnection('page');
  await cdpConnection.execute(
    'Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument', {
      source: `
          const newProto = navigator.__proto__;
          delete newProto.webdriver;
          navigator.__proto__ = newProto;
      `
    }
  );

  try {
    await driver.get("https://seller.ozon.ru/app/registration/signin?auth=1");
    await driver.sleep(200)
    await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('input[type="tel"]')), 2000).sendKeys('9183464580');
    await driver.sleep(200)
    await driver.findElement(By.css('button[type="submit"]')).click();
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
})();
```